# error: member access into incomplete type''; note: forward declaration of ''

Tags: c++, struct

Here is a struct MAIN which have member struct A and struct B, the code is like below

```
// a.hpp
#ifndef _A_HPP_
#define _A_HPP_
struct A
{
    int mem1;
};
#endif
```

```
// b.hpp
#ifndef _B_HPP_
#define _B_HPP_

#include "a.hpp"
#include "main.hpp"
struct MAIN;
struct A;

struct B{
    int mem2;
    MAIN* main;
    A *aptr;
    B(){
        *aptr=this->main->a;
    }
};


#endif
```

```
// main.hpp
#ifndef _MAIN_HPP_
#define _MAIN_HPP_

#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"

struct MAIN{
    A a;
    B b;
};

#endif
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "main.hpp"
int main(){
    MAIN m;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to use the aptr in struct B to visit A which in the same MAIN, but compile error like

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
In file included from ./main.hpp:6:
./b.hpp:15:25: error: member access into incomplete type 'MAIN'
        *aptr=this->main->a;
                        ^
./b.hpp:7:8: note: forward declaration of 'MAIN'
struct MAIN;
       ^
1 error generated.
```

How the error occured? my code should use struct but not class, and hpp but not h with cpp. Is there anyway to fix it? Hope for help

Comment: Removed c tag as this is a c++ question.

Comment: In b.hpp you want to leave out `#include "main.hpp"` (as that is where you use the forward declaration) and leave out `struct A;` (as you are including it).  @dbush already gave you the answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the constructor `B::B` inside the struct definition references members of `MAIN`, but the latter hasn't been fully defined yet.

You need to move the body of constructor `B::B` into a separate file, i.e. b.cpp, and link with main.cpp when building the executable.